# How to get last item of a specific column in tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I want to get the last item value of a specific column. How do you do this? All I know is to get all value of tkinter treeview. I have tried everything, but I am still clueless. The code I did below get error *TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable*. I want the data of the get_latest_value to be able to make calculation, such as get_latest_value_frozen * 30

```
for child in OUT_DC_Level_data_table.get_children():
        item_values = OUT_DC_Level_data_table.item(child)['values']
        get_latest_value_OUT_DC_level_frozen = int(OUT_DC_Level_data_table.item(child)['values'][1][-1])
        get_latest_value_OUT_DC_level_chill = int(OUT_DC_Level_data_table.item(child)['values'][1][-1])
        get_latest_value_OUT_DC_level_dry = int(OUT_DC_Level_data_table.item(child)['values'][1][-1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you get the *item ID* of the last item, then use `.set(item_id, column_name)` to get the required values:

```py
# get the item ID of the last item
item_id = OUT_DC_Level_data_table.get_children()[-1]
# get the value of column "frozen" for example
get_latest_value_OUT_DC_level_frozen = int(OUT_DC_Level_data_table.set(item_id, "frozen"))
# get values of other columns similarly
```

Comment: Can i ask clarifying question? What if I want to get the value last item of a specific column more than once? How do you make this?

Comment: Do you mean to get values of several columns at the last item? If yes, then use `.item(item_id, "values")` to get all the values of the last item and access the required columns in the returned list.

Comment: No. I mean, I'm trying to create an automatic prediction button. I was thinking of getting the last item of a specific column by itself and make calculation. I was thinking of using a for loops to automate the process. For instance, for _ in range(3):
    items_id = tree.get_children()[-1]
     get_latest_value_frozen = int(OUT_DC_Level_data_table.set(item_id, "frozen"))

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you want. Maybe you raise another question.

Comment: It's okay. Thank you so much :) I figured out my problem on my own with the help of your solution!